# pagination does not work in orders WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

i changed the pagination of WooCommerce orders as follows :

- before : example.com/my-account/orders/2
- after : example.com/my-account/orders/page/2

i added pagination to WooCommerce orders

path : /plugins/woocommerce/templates/myaccount/orders.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Orders
 *
 * Shows orders on the account page.
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/myaccount/orders.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package WooCommerce\Templates
 * @version 3.7.0
 */

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

do_action( 'woocommerce_before_account_orders', $has_orders ); 

?>

<?php if ( $has_orders ) : ?>

    <table class="woocommerce-orders-table woocommerce-MyAccount-orders shop_table shop_table_responsive my_account_orders account-orders-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <?php foreach ( wc_get_account_orders_columns() as $column_id => $column_name ) : ?>
                    <th class="woocommerce-orders-table__header woocommerce-orders-table__header-<?php echo esc_attr( $column_id ); ?>"><span class="nobr"><?php echo esc_html( $column_name ); ?></span></th>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <?php
            foreach ( $customer_orders->orders as $customer_order ) {
                $order      = wc_get_order( $customer_order ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.WP.GlobalVariablesOverride.Prohibited
                $item_count = $order->get_item_count() - $order->get_item_count_refunded();
                ?>
                <tr class="woocommerce-orders-table__row woocommerce-orders-table__row--status-<?php echo esc_attr( $order->get_status() ); ?> order">
                    <?php foreach ( wc_get_account_orders_columns() as $column_id => $column_name ) : ?>
                        <td class="woocommerce-orders-table__cell woocommerce-orders-table__cell-<?php echo esc_attr( $column_id ); ?>" data-title="<?php echo esc_attr( $column_name ); ?>">
                            <?php if ( has_action( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_' . $column_id ) ) : ?>
                                <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_' . $column_id, $order ); ?>

                            <?php elseif ( 'order-number' === $column_id ) : ?>
                                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $order->get_view_order_url() ); ?>">
                                    <?php echo esc_html( $order->get_order_number() ); ?>
                                </a>

                            <?php elseif ( 'order-date' === $column_id ) : ?>
                                <time datetime="<?php echo esc_attr( $order->get_date_created()->date( 'c' ) ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( wc_format_datetime( $order->get_date_created() ) ); ?></time>

                            <?php elseif ( 'order-total' === $column_id ) : ?>
                                <?php echo $order->get_formatted_order_total(); ?>

                            <?php elseif ( 'order-status' === $column_id ) : ?>
                                <?php echo esc_html( wc_get_order_status_name( $order->get_status() ) ); ?>

                            <?php elseif ( 'order-actions' === $column_id ) : ?>
                                <?php
                                $actions = wc_get_account_orders_actions( $order );

                                if ( ! empty( $actions ) ) {
                                    foreach ( $actions as $key => $action ) { // phpcs:ignore WordPress.WP.GlobalVariablesOverride.Prohibited
                                        echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $action['url'] ) . '" class="woocommerce-button button ' . sanitize_html_class( $key ) . '">' . esc_html( $action['name'] ) . '</a>';
                                    }
                                }
                                ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </td>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </tr>
                <?php
            }
            ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_account_orders_pagination' ); ?>

    <?php if ( 1 < $customer_orders->max_num_pages ) : ?>
        <nav class="woocommerce-pagination">
            <?php
                $args = array(
                    'total'    => $customer_orders->max_num_pages
                );
                echo paginate_links( $args );
            ?>
        </nav>
    <?php endif; ?>

<?php else : ?>
    <p class="woocommerce_message"><?php esc_html_e( 'No order has been made yet.', 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_account_orders', $has_orders ); ?>
```

i also added the following code to functions :

```
function woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query1() {
    $current_page = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? (int) get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
    $customer_orders = array(
        'customer' => get_current_user_id(),
        'page'     => $current_page,
        'paginate' => true,
    );
    return $customer_orders;
} add_filter( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query', 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query1', 10, 1 );
```

**problem :** after clicking on any of the page numbers, it will go to the correct address, that is:

- example.com/my-account/orders/page/2
- example.com/my-account/orders/page/3
- example.com/my-account/orders/page/4

but in all pages it brings the same results as the first page

i did a lot of searching on the internet and i tried everything, but it didn't work, for example :

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/185600/pagination-not-working

if you would like to answer my question, thanks

Comment: The possible issue you are facing is maybe you get the wrong `$current_page` please echo that variable and check if you are getting the same number or a different number?

Comment: thank you for taking the time to answer my question, yes, i was thinking the same thing, and before asking this question, i changed the `$current_page` variable value several times, but it did not work. now, as you said, i executed the `$current_page` variable, the value it returns is 1 in all pages.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your issue, make use of `WP_Query` as it seems that you are using a custom page template here.

```
'paged' => ( get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1),
```

should be

```
'paged' => ( get_query_var('page') ? get_query_var('page') : 1),
```

as static front pages use `page` and not `paged`

Comment: thanks again for taking the time to answer my question, i had tested this thing that you mentioned before i asked the question, but it didn't work, maybe i'm not using it correctly, please help me more

Comment: Still, you are getting 1 in all pages?

Comment: yes, all pages return 1

Comment: I think it's now required more debugging.

Comment: thank you once again for taking the time to answer my question, i have been looking for a solution for the problem for a few days now. i tested it on another site and saw that the same problem exists. the problem must be with the code that i placed.

Comment: umm, can i have access? maybe i can debug directly there?

Comment: now i installed a WordPress and WooCommerce with the twentytwentytwo template and tested the code, the same problem still exists. i think 100% of the problem is from the code i wrote, please answer me, thank you very much for the recent answers.

Answer (score 0):

## Update 2 with solution, tested and working

I write the result directly, so if you don't like it, don't waste time implementing the code. Not quite exactly what you were looking for, but the most I managed to do is this: **example.com/my-account/orders/page/?n=2**

I looked at the topic all day, looked for similar questions and studied the reference https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/paginate_links/, but couldn't get it to work as described in your question. It is also in my interest to achieve a similar result, I want to understand how it works. In any case, we are waiting for someone who knows the subject well, maybe he will be able to give a better answer.

As for the previous update, I will write you what I did step by step

**1**. Go to /themes/theme-child/woocommerce/myaccount

**2**. If you have the order.php file open it, otherwise create it. Then you will have /themes/theme-child/woocommerce/myaccount/orders.php

**3**. Inside the orders.php file paste the following template, this time I added custom queries at the beginning and changed the final part slightly.

```
<?php
/**
 * Orders
 *
 * Shows orders on the account page.
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/myaccount/orders.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package WooCommerce\Templates
 * @version 3.7.0
 */

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

do_action( 'woocommerce_before_account_orders', $has_orders ); 

?>

<?php if ( $has_orders ) : ?>
  <?php
  $paged = max( 1, (int) filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'n' ) );
  $customer_orders = wc_get_orders( apply_filters('woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query',array(
    'customer_id'     => get_current_user_id(),
    'posts_per_page' => 3, // post per page
    'paged'          => $paged,
    'paginate'       => true,
  )));
  ?>

  <table class="woocommerce-orders-table woocommerce-MyAccount-orders shop_table shop_table_responsive my_account_orders account-orders-table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <?php foreach ( wc_get_account_orders_columns() as $column_id => $column_name ) : ?>
          <th class="woocommerce-orders-table__header woocommerce-orders-table__header-<?php echo esc_attr( $column_id ); ?>"><span class="nobr"><?php echo esc_html( $column_name ); ?></span></th>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <?php
        foreach ( $customer_orders->orders as $customer_order ) {
          $order      = wc_get_order( $customer_order ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.WP.GlobalVariablesOverride.Prohibited
          $item_count = $order->get_item_count() - $order->get_item_count_refunded();
          ?>
            <tr class="woocommerce-orders-table__row woocommerce-orders-table__row--status-<?php echo esc_attr( $order->get_status() ); ?> order">
              <?php foreach ( wc_get_account_orders_columns() as $column_id => $column_name ) : ?>
                <td class="woocommerce-orders-table__cell woocommerce-orders-table__cell-<?php echo esc_attr( $column_id ); ?>" data-title="<?php echo esc_attr( $column_name ); ?>">
                  <?php if ( has_action( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_' . $column_id ) ) : ?>
                    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_' . $column_id, $order ); ?>

                    <?php elseif ( 'order-number' === $column_id ) : ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $order->get_view_order_url() ); ?>">
                      <?php echo esc_html( $order->get_order_number() ); ?>
                    </a>

                    <?php elseif ( 'order-date' === $column_id ) : ?>
                    <time datetime="<?php echo esc_attr( $order->get_date_created()->date( 'c' ) ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( wc_format_datetime( $order->get_date_created() ) ); ?></time>

                    <?php elseif ( 'order-total' === $column_id ) : ?>
                    <?php echo $order->get_formatted_order_total(); ?>

                    <?php elseif ( 'order-status' === $column_id ) : ?>
                    <?php echo esc_html( wc_get_order_status_name( $order->get_status() ) ); ?>

                    <?php elseif ( 'order-actions' === $column_id ) : ?>
                    <?php
                      $actions = wc_get_account_orders_actions( $order );
                      if ( ! empty( $actions ) ) {
                        foreach ( $actions as $key => $action ) { // phpcs:ignore WordPress.WP.GlobalVariablesOverride.Prohibited
                          echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $action['url'] ) . '" class="woocommerce-button button ' . sanitize_html_class( $key ) . '">' . esc_html( $action['name'] ) . '</a>';
                        }
                      }
                    ?>
                  <?php endif; ?>
                </td>
              <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tr>
          <?php
        }
      ?>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_account_orders_pagination' ); ?>
  <nav class="woocommerce-pagination">
    <?php
      echo paginate_links(array(
        'base'          => esc_url( wc_get_endpoint_url( 'orders') ) . 'page/%_%', // Base of the paginated url.
        'format'        => '?n=%#%', // Format for the pagination structure.
        'total'         => $customer_orders->max_num_pages, // The total amount of pages. Default is the value WP_Query's max_num_pages or 1.
        'current'       => $paged, // The current page number. Default is 'paged' query var or 1.
        'show_all'      => false, // Whether to show all pages. Default false.
        'end_size'      => 3, // How many numbers on either the start and the end list edges. Default 1.
        'mid_size'      => 3, // How many numbers to either side of the current pages. Default 2.
        'prev_next'     => true, // Whether to include the previous and next links in the list. Default true.
        'prev_text'      => __('<span>« Prev</span>'), // The previous page text. Default '« Previous'.
        'next_text'     => __('<span>Next »</span>'), // The next page text. Default 'Next »'.
      )); 
    ?> 
  </nav> 

  <?php else : ?>
  <p class="woocommerce_message"><?php esc_html_e( 'No order has been made yet.', 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_account_orders', $has_orders ); ?>
```

**4**. In the functions.php file remove the following function, I had it added to you in the previous update, but since you now have a custom query you don't need the code below.

```
// Query Post - How many orders do you want to display per page in the orders.php template ?
add_filter( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query', 'custom_my_account_orders', 10, 1 );
function custom_my_account_orders( $args ) {
   // Set the post per page
   $args['limit'] = 6;
   return $args;
}
```

**5**. Still in the functions.php file, delete what you did previously, you don't need it.

```
function woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query1() {
    $current_page = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? (int) get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
    $customer_orders = array(
        'customer' => get_current_user_id(),
        'page'     => $current_page,
        'paginate' => true,
    );
    return $customer_orders;
} add_filter( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query', 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query1', 10, 1 );
```

Try and let us know if it works, hope this helps.

Comment: thank you for taking the time to answer my question, in the child theme, i made changes in the WooCommerce file, which means: /themes/theme-child/woocommerce/myaccount/orders.php, i had done something like this before i asked the question, but it didn't work. i even put this code in the orders.php file in the $args array section, but it didn't work

Comment: Check the answer, I have updated the solution. I have also tested it and it works fine. You shouldn't have any problems if you do everything correctly. Obviously remember to leave the original files in the /plugins/woocommerce/templates/myaccount/orders.php folder otherwise it may not work.

Comment: thank you again for taking the time to answer my question, read my first question again, i want to add /page/ to the orders url, for example : before : example.com/my-account/orders/2 | after : example.com/my-account/orders/page/2, this answer that you kindly gave, /page/ will not be added to the orders

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't considered that part, I was just focusing on making pagination work. Then I modify my answer to include page in the link.

Comment: don't be sorry, thank you for taking the time to answer my question, i am waiting for a guide, please

Comment: Have a look at the update of my answer. I hope it reflects your needs a little but I couldn't do better. I am also waiting for an answer from someone who can solve the problem.

Comment: although it was not exactly what i wanted, i must thank you for your time, i searched many sites before asking the question but i did not get the result, i am still waiting for someone to kindly answer my question.